# Docker, can't start the container

Tags: ruby, docker

Currently, I'm studying Cucumber and other gems and I need to use Docker.

My problem is that I can't start the needed container; the following code to do so is:

```
docker run --name pgadmin --network=skynet -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=root@qaninja.io' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=qaninja' -p 15432:80 -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

the pulling is done correctly but the container don't start, even if I try `docker run pgadmin` i get:

> Unable to find image 'pgadmin:latest' locally
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for pgadmin, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

`docker start pgadmin` shows `pgadmin` but nothing really happens.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't start?  Does it produce any interesting log messages?

Comment: when ´´´docker ps -a´´´ it shows "exited". but it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but please try this:

```
docker run --name pgadmin --rm -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=root@qaninja.io' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=qaninja' -p 15432:80 dpage/pgadmin4
```

and then open your browser on http://0.0.0.0:15432

I think the `-d` is what's causing you problems. And I think the network *skynet* may not exist.

If that doesn't help, please please provide the full output of the above command by editing your question. And remember to format the output so that it looks good on stack overflow.

Comment: The container was successfully created, but I just can't start it, the network exists because I have other container working completely fine.

Comment: If that doesn't help, please please provide the full output of the above command by editing your question. And remember to format the output so that it looks good on stack overflow.